Proof verification - probability (independence)
(This is a random idea I had during another problem - just wanting to check my logic is correct).
Is it always true that if $P(A)+P(A'|B)=1$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent events?
Here $A'$ is the complement of $A$.
My reason for saying yes is as follows:
If $P(A)+P(A'|B)=1$ then $P(A'|B)=1-P(A)$
Therefore $P(A'|B)=P(A')$
Therefore $A'$ and $B$ are independent events.
But... does this automatically mean that $A$ and $B$ are independent?
It seems intuitive that yes, they are, but I want to know if I have missed a counter-example.
Thanks.

$P(A'|B)=P(A')$ is equivalent to $1-P(A|B)=1-P(A)$.

You proof is correct.

Thanks - I was mostly worries about the final line because not everything that seems intuitively correct is mathematically correct.

Intuition cannot be used. In fact, intuition leads to wrong conclusions many times. You have to know how to prove that independence of $A'$ and $B$ implies that of $A$ and $B$,

Yes, agree. Hence my posting the question. The readers and commenters on this site are far more knowledgeable than I am - I learn more here than I do from textbooks.
